# Have some priority sorting for compound NSPredicate

Tags: swift, database, nspredicate

I have some data like the following:

```
NAME | LAST_NAME | PLACE

Roger - Martins - Miami
Mary - Rogers - Paris
Jack - Smith - Maryland
Alfred - Cooper - Germany

... and many more
```

And I have a predicate like this:

```
let searchPredicateName = NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.Name + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", _searchString)
let searchPredicateLastName = NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.LastName + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", _searchString)
let searchPredicatePlace = NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.Place + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", _searchString)

let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [searchPredicateTitle, searchPredicateLastName, searchPredicatePlace])
```

When I search for example "Mar" then the results I would get will be:

```
Roger - Martins - Miami
Mary - Rogers - Paris
Jack - Smith - Maryland
```

The results are OK, but I would like to have Mary Rogers first. One option would be to fetch separately but then I wouldn't have one NSFetchedResultsController as a datasource and that would impact the performance

Comment: What has this got to do with the `xcode-ui-testing` tag?

Comment: @paulvs sorry, don't know how that happened, fixed

Comment: Does `NSSortDescriptor` help?

Comment: @paulvs but how would that NSSortDescriptor be? I know how to use them to compare the values of one field in the data model but to give priority to one field over another, no idea

Comment: What sort ordering would put Mary Rogers first? Alphabetical by first name, it would be Jack, Mary, Roger. By surname, it would be Martins, Rogers, Smith. By location, it would be Maryland, Miami, Paris. You can always sort by a non-displayed criteria, but we would have to know how you are picking the order you want them to be in.

Comment: How are you using the predicate within the fetched results controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually looking for is `NSSortDescriptor`.
When you use `NSFetchedResultsController` your `NSFetchRequest` has to have a sort descriptor -- that's when you do the sorting.

`NSPredicate` is for comparing. ie: What you want to find.

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true),// sort by section key first
                                 NSSortDescriptor(key:  "Name", ascending: true), //continue sorting by first name
                                 NSSortDescriptor(key:  "LastName", ascending: true), //continue sorting by last name.
                                 NSSortDescriptor(key: "Place", ascending: true)] //finally by place.
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing comments from hush-entangle above I can clearly see my answer is completely wrong. I was a little too excited to get started on this website.. You are actually searching for a string position, likely using a UISearchController yeah? In that case you want to sort your results ie:

```
func sortForString(_ string: String) -> [Person] {
     
   let string = string.lowerCased()

   // searchResultsArray or if you want all just sort the fetched objects
    (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
    personInfoString(lhs).range(of: string ).lowerBound < personInfoString(rhs).range(of: string ).lowerBound
})) ?? [Person]()
  }

func personInfoString(_ person: Person) -> NSString {
    (person.first ?? "").appending(person.last ?? "").appending(person.place ?? "").lowercased() as NSString
}

let sorted = sortForString("Mar")
```

Then display your sorted strings.
Notice if the search string is not contained the original order remains.

cleaned up might be

```
extension Person {
func sortableString() -> NSString {
    (self.first ?? " ").appending(self.last ?? " ").appending(self.place ?? " ").lowercased() as NSString
     }
}


 extension NSFetchedResultsController where ResultType == Person {

    func sortedObjects(for searchString: String) -> [Person] {
         (self.fetchedObjects?.sorted(by: { lhs, rhs in
        lhs.sortableString().range(of: searchString ).lowerBound < rhs.sortableString().range(of: searchString ).lowerBound
         })) ?? [Person]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that NSPredicate has no way to call a method. This means you cannot sort with predicate only filter or search. Unfortunately, you also cannot use a comparator for the sort descriptor of an NSFetchRequest. This means that the sort must happen separately from the original fetch. I hope this helps. You may want to review docs on the UISearchController too. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some entity `UserMO` with fields `name`, `lastName` and `place`. Also, I assume that you are using the `UISearchController`.

To sort by name, use the `NSSortDescriptor`. We omit the predicate, since we initially want to display all the elements. Based on this, we will write a function for creating a controller:

```
func createFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<UserMO> {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<UserMO> = UserMO.fetchRequest()
   request.sortDescriptors = [
      NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \UserMO.name, ascending: true)
   ]
   return NSFetchedResultsController<UserMO>(
      fetchRequest: request, 
      managedObjectContext: context,
      sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
      cacheName: nil)
}
```

At the moment when the user edits the search string, the delegate method `updateSearchResults` will be called. There, depending on what the user entered, we edit the predicate. You don't need to change the sorting rules.

```
extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

   func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
      let text = searchController.searchBar.text ?? ""
      let predicate: NSPredicate?
      if text.isEmpty {
         predicate = nil // We want to display all items
      } else {
         predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
            NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.Name + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", text),
            NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.LastName + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", text),
            NSPredicate(format: Database.Key.Place + " CONTAINS[cd] %@", text),
         ])
      }
      fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
      
      do {
         try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
      } catch {
         print(error)
      }
   }

}
```